# How to get rid of Angular6 typescript error?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services

I'm building an angular 6 project with typescript 3.1.2. I'm calling a restful API that returns a JSON data set with a label name data.  I'm getting the below error but the website works perfectly without any console error. Is this a bug or I'm I doing something wrong?

```
error TS2339: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'AgentData[]'.
```

Json Data:
[image]

Here is my class:
[image]

Here is my Service:
[image]

Here is my Agent Component subscribing to the service.
[image]

This is the error from VS Code Editor:

```
[ts] Property 'data' does not exist on type 'AgentData[]'
```

Comment: I voted to close this question, because the code is in the form of images, not text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your method return type should be `Observable<AgentData>` instead of `Observable<AgentData[]>`

Answer (score 0):

your are looking for resp.data where resp is an array. you should be looking for resp[0].data